# Why does this C++ code get SIGILL on ideone.com?

Tags: c++, gcc

Why does it happen? The code works and generates no warnings with GCC 4.7 on Linux and MSVC++ 2010 on Windows. Yet, on ideone.com it [crashes](http://ideone.com/kOKBm) with `SIGILL`. Is undefined behavior involved here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

using namespace std;

enum types
{
    INT,
    DOUBLE,
    CHAR,
    STRING
};

struct mt
{
    types type;

    union
    {
        int         i;
        double      d;
        char        c;
        const char *s;
    } val;

    mt(int i)
        : type(INT)
    {
        val.i = i;
    }

    mt(double d)
        : type(DOUBLE)
    {
        val.d = d;
    }

    mt(char c)
        : type(CHAR)
    {
        val.c = c;
    }

    mt(const char *s)
        : type(STRING)
    {
        val.s = s;
    }
};

void print(int n, ...)
{
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mt x(va_arg(ap, mt));

        switch (x.type)
        {
        case INT:
            cout << x.val.i << endl;
            break;
        case DOUBLE:
            cout << x.val.d << endl;
            break;
        case CHAR:
            cout << x.val.c << endl;
            break;
        case STRING:
            cout << x.val.s << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    va_end(ap);
}

int main()
{
    print(4, mt(2), mt(4.2), mt('a'), mt("Hello"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got errors with GCC 4.4.6:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void print(int, ...)’:
test.cpp:59: warning: cannot receive objects of non-POD type ‘struct mt’ through ‘...’; call will abort at runtime
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:83: warning: cannot pass objects of non-POD type ‘struct mt’ through ‘...’; call will abort at runtime
test.cpp:83: warning: cannot pass objects of non-POD type ‘struct mt’ through ‘...’; call will abort at runtime
test.cpp:83: warning: cannot pass objects of non-POD type ‘struct mt’ through ‘...’; call will abort at runtime
test.cpp:83: warning: cannot pass objects of non-POD type ‘struct mt’ through ‘...’; call will abort at runtime
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)
```

You cannot pass `struct`s through varargs function parameters, instead pass pointers:

```
void print(int n, ...)
{
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mt *x(va_arg(ap, mt *));

        switch (x->type)
        {
        case INT:
            cout << x->val.i << endl;
            break;
        case DOUBLE:
            cout << x->val.d << endl;
            break;
        case CHAR:
            cout << x->val.c << endl;
            break;
        case STRING:
            cout << x->val.s << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    va_end(ap);
}

int main()
{
    mt mt1(2);
    mt mt2(4.2);
    mt mt3('a');
    mt mt4("Hello");
    print(4, &mt1, &mt2, &mt3, &mt4);
}
```

Which works fine on my system:

```
$ ./a.out
2
4.2
a
Hello
```

Comment: I've thought one can pass anything that is POD (see C++03, 5.2.2.7, "_or class type_"). And `struct mt` looks POD to me, because (a) it doesn't have non-POD members, (b) it doesn't have a user-defined copy assignment operator and (c) it doesn't have a user-defined destructor (see Clause 9). Is this deduction wrong?

Comment: @AndreyVihrov Varargs are something of a hack and are non-portable (as you have found out).  Use `std::<vector>` or some other collection class to pass objects between methods.

Comment: I disagree. Varargs are portable, because they are officially part of both C and C++ standards :-)

Comment: @AndreyVihrov But you have found problems yourself already - it worked under VS2010 and g++ 4.7 but not on ideone.com or my system.  See if using pointers is portable and then I'll agree with you :)

Comment: I'm not a C++ expert, but I think it's to do with the standard, try `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x`.  They *added* "... or of POD class types" to the definition of POD type

Comment: @Andrey - A POD-struct is required to be an *aggregate*. That excludes user defined constructors as well (8.5.1).

Comment: @BoPersson: That's it! You should definitely post this as an answer.